Using Windows 8, Blender v2.7 and can't seem to edit an object upon creation, what am I missing?
I only used blender years ago when I was in highschool. I still have the same desktop (and don't have access to anything more modern), it has Windows 8 and I remember back when I started using this program, it was fairly simple to use.
It still seems simple, but the one feature I was hoping would work just like before is this popup that allowed me to alter or modify or change some details about the objects I created. But instead, pressing F6 only shows a greyed out pop-up window I can't interact with and anything else I found asks me to press keys and macros that don't do anything whether it's related to my blender version, my keyboard or my OS.
I remember having to use a specific version of programs like 3DSMAX because they weren't compatible with my OS, so I'm assuming I have to get another version of Blender too.
It could also be me, that I'm just not doing something the way it's supposed to be done. I apologize English is not my native tongue.
Should I try and make blender work or am I better off using some other program?

I've never used Blender 2.7 and don’t have access to it. Since 2.7 is quite old, it maybe hard to  get answers. However, if you're open to it, you might consider upgrading to a newer version of Blender. You can follow this tutorial for installing a more recent version. While the tutorial is geared towards Windows 7, it might work for Windows 8 as well. It has worked for many others based on feedback, but please proceed with caution, as there’s a risk it could potentially affect your system, esp. with DLL installations. Proceed at your own risk.

Latest version of Blender can run on Windows 8.1, no special version needed. See recommended requirements https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ 2.7 is quite old though, so why don't you describe what you are trying to do so we can recommend an equivalent workflows for current versions of Blender

You mean edit mode? (keyboard =tab)

If you mean the Adjust Last Operation panel where you can do things like change the number of vertices on a cylinder or the resolution of a UV sphere for example, I don't know if that was F6 back then but it's F9 for a long time now, maybe try this. Apart from that, it is not possible to bring up the settings anymore if you did any other action after adding the object. It only shows the parameters of whatever was the last action.
